# Roll back rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have installed Rails 3.2.13 (gem install rails -v 3.2.13) currently. But for some reasons I needed roll back to version 3.2.13. How can I do it?
Now:

```
> rails -v    
You have requested:

  rails = 3.2.13

The bundle currently has rails locked at 3.2.12.
Try running `bundle update rails`
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Gemfile, look for the `gem 'rails'` line and change it to

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
```

then run `bundle install`